# Modifying a dynamic 2D array in a function

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I've got a function that accepts a dynamic multidimensional array (which is initialized to 0) as a parameter, and I'm trying to modify certain values within the array in my function.

The function that accepts the array as a parameter is supposed to simulate the roll of two dice and output the frequency distribution to the array I made that's initialized to zero.

The code for it is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int** rollDie(int numRolls, unsigned short seed, int** &rollarray)
{
srand(seed);
int side1, side2;
while (numRolls > 0)
{
side1 = 1 + rand() % 6;
side2 = 1 + rand() % 6;

rollarray[side1][side2]++;

numRolls--;
}
return rollarray;

}

int** initializeArray(void)
{
    int i, j;
    int** m = new int*[6];

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        m[i] = new int[6];

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            m[i][j] = 0;

    return m;
}

int main()
{
int numRolls;
unsigned short seed;
int ** a = initializeArray();


cout << "rolls?\n";
cin >> numRolls;

cout << "seed?\n";
cin >> seed;
int ** b = rollDie(numRolls, seed, a);

int i,j;
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        cout << b[i][j];
    }
    cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: where do you initialise a?

Comment: a is initialized in a function that makes a 6x6 array of zeroes. I tested that in main and was able to print out the array properly.

Comment: What is "doesn't run properly", how is properly?

Comment: This still prints out a 6x6 array of zeroes. None of the numbers have been modified.

Comment: Sure, you're not passing it as a reference, you should use int** &rollarray instead, or make a copy and return the modified copy, or int &rollarray[][], for better reading

Comment: Some mnemonics,, to access the mem dir of an int for example you need a int &, so for a int[] you need a int& [] and so on

Comment: 1)  Are you sure numRolls is greater than 0?  2)  What value are you using for the seed?  3)  It looks like you're resetting the seed each time you call the function.  You should only set it once - otherwise, you always get the same two values in each iteration.

Comment: DGomez, I'm not really following. I changed the parameter in rollDie to pass by value, but it's still doing the same thing? I am appreciating the help though!

Comment: @DGomez - I think you're wrong about the reference and the return. I've run the program and it works - `a` is a pointer, and you want to change what it points to, so no need to pass it by reference... Remember that the array is dynamically allocated, so not a 2D array but an array of 1D arrays

Comment: 4)  Make sure that "a" is indeed a pointer to a pointer to an array.  Without seeing the declaration of a, I'm guessing you're writing to somewhere in memory you aren't expecting.

Comment: @Steve, I edited the original post to show the entire program. Did I declare a wrong? I'm having a really difficult time wrapping my head around some of these concepts.

Comment: @bc8787 - you declared `a` and the `initializeArray` perfectly. as far as I can see the bug is only in the `1+rand()%6` line - just remove the `1+`. Oh, and BTW - you don't need `b` at all! `rollDie` doesn't need to return anything - it changes the data pointed to by `a`, just print `a` instead of `b` after the `rollDie`\

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed - remove the `&` from `rollDie`. You don't need it in this code. It is actually wrong.

Comment: @cluracan I tried that too. For some reason it's still outputting zeroes :(

Comment: http://ideone.com/SNa8s8, here is a working example

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just before you posted that I switched rollarray[side1][side2]++ to rollarray[side1][side2] += 1. For whatever reason, that worked.

Comment: @bc8787 - run your exact code - segmentation fault. Run your exact code after removing the `1+` and the `&` (no other changes at all), worked perfectly.

Comment: @DGomez - your code is wrong and has bugs. Specifically, the `1+rand()` is a bug - as you change indexes 1-6 instead of 0-5 (and although you created arrays of length 7, you only created 6 of them so it should still do a segmentation fault). Also you don't need the `&`.

Comment: @bc8787 - the ++ should work just as well as the +=1...

Answer (score 1):

Code works for me with just a few issues (I had to guess how you defined `a`. Next time add that too):

In the printing you should print a space after every number (minor)

In the random, you choose index as `1+rand()%6`, so from 1 to 6, but when you print you take indexes from 0 to 5! So your first row and first column will be 0.

Other than that it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Only when one goes and does something else does the answer come to mind.  I suspect you declared a as:

```
int a[6][6];
```

which is an array of 36 integers.  In your function, though, you're declaring rollarray to be a pointer to an array of pointers to integers.  All you need to do is change the function signature to:

```
int* rollDie(int numRolls, unsigned short seed, int* rollarray)
```

As cluracan said, you also want to use array indices in the range 0 to 5.

This is a good case for either the judicious use of print statements or stepping through with a debugger to see what's really going on.

Comment: He edited his question to show he declared `a` as an array of arrays

Comment: Which, of course, leads to the question "Why???  Why make it so much more complicated than it needs to be?"  :-)